# sh: grep absent elements (BSD grep)

Tags: grep, sh

I am attempting to find difference between two variables:

`left='f012 f013'` and `right='f012 f013 f014'`.

I need find all f* which is absent in the left side. I have also tried the following which also doesn't work:

`echo 'f012 f013' | grep -o -v 'f012 f013 f014'`

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: (1) `grep` works on lines of input, so what you're attempting doesn't make sense.  (2) This seems like a XY problem.  It'd be better to tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, look. Two variables. `left='f012 f013'`, `right='f012 f013 f014'`. I am attempting find different element. In this example this is `f014`

Comment: @jaypal Not trolling, please

Comment: @Andry You should update your original post with this, since it makes your question different.  With `grep -o` it prints only the found part, so you are trying to find some thing not in there, it will just not print nothing, since `f012 f013` does not contain `f012 f013 f014`

Comment: I know, but I have specified `-v` flag which invert the result

Comment: Ok ,guys. Below man have specified me right way. And don't post any non constructive drivel like @jaypal

Comment: @Andry `grep -vf <(printf "%s\n" $left) <(printf "%s\n" $right)`. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Andry It seems that your request has change a lot since your question. Please update your original post.

Comment: @jaypal  `Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting word)`

Comment: @Andry on your prompt before typing the command, type `bash` to allow process substitution.

Comment: @jaypal  grep -vf <\`printf "%s\n" $left\` <\`printf "%s\n" $right\`
`cannot open f012`

Comment: @jaypal, please stop posting. I use sh. Not bash. Read initial message

Comment: @Andry Then it may be time to upgrade to `bash`. I would guess your system has it, so its just matter of typing `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`

Answer (score 0):

Most *nix tools require you to have one item per line, and [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) might be more appropriate:

```
$ cat haystack
f012
f013
$ cat needles
f012
f013
f014
$ comm -13 haystack needles
f014
```

From [`man comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm), `-13` suppresses lines from column 1 (lines unique to FILE1, *ie.* `haystack`, your command's output) and column 3 (lines that appear in both files), leaving lines unique to FILE2, *ie.* `needles`, the `f*` you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you friend. Comm is suitable for me. One-per-line by `echo -e "bla bla bla"` (in FreeBSD)

Comment: This compare files, not variables, and how to find what is different within one line with this. It just compare complete line with another complete line. not field by field.

Comment: @Jotne The "var" precision came after my answer, and as mentionned by @jaypal it is simply a matter of `<(printf "%s\n" $var)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  `diff` to compare the variable, but you need to get them into separate lines, or else it just compare the complete line, not every fields:

```
diff <(awk -v RS=" |\n" '$1=$1' <<<"$left") <(awk -v RS=" |\n" '$1=$1' <<<"$right")
2a3
> f014
```